# Discrete scrolling in listview android

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I need to make some kind of slot machine on android, so I have three endless circular listviews with pictures. Question is how to keep items in row every time after user`s scroll? I tried to implement onScrollStateChanged and scroll item after scroll stops little bit more, but it has no effect

Answer (score 0):

```
    AbsListView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new AbsListView.OnScrollListener(){
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
           if(i == 0)
           {
                  ListView.setSelection(ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) 
        {

        }
    };

    yourList.setOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
```

hope that helps